# Let's bring [tables] to the table

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tables) is a very broad tag, which currently has no tag wiki and encompasses everything from questions about Excel, SQL tables, tables in Microsoft Word, and a whole host of other things. In other words, it doesn't represent a single area of expertise.

I feel that the MS Word ones could *possibly* be split into a [microsoft-word-tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-tables) tag, as that is a specific function set under Word that people do have specific problems with formatting, etc. But the rest of the questions I feel don't actually need the tag at all, and it could be removed outright.

Thoughts?

Comment: The tag is quite meaningless; I'd just remove it altogether.

Comment: @slhck - sure, it was only a suggestion to split out the ms word tables :-)

Comment: It might be worth having an excel-tables tag as well, since the syntax for referring to data in Excel tables is different than regular range references. I haven't looked through the tagged questions to see if the tag is used for that, but there are conceivably some issues that relate specifically to this.

Comment: Upon review, most of the questions tagged with `tables` and `microsoft-excel` are not about Excel tables in the technical sense. If used properly, the `excel-tables` tag would be pretty sparse. Worse yet, the questions here suggest the tag would be misapplied pretty often.

Comment: @Excellll - Yeah I'd advise against [excel-tables]. It all comes down to fields of expertise. From a layman's point of view, Excel is software that deals with tables as its core function - so simply tagging with [microsoft-excel] *should* be enough if your question is about creating/modifying tables. Other largish subsections of the application, such as Macros, may require specialist knowledge that isn't relevant to the layman, or even necessary to use excel competently 80% of the time. Thus, having a [microsoft-excel-macros] subtag may be a good option, as it's a specific field of expertise.

Comment: I should also mention that I've seen it also used as a typo tag for [tag:tablet].

Answer (score 3):

I agree that [tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tables) is overly broad and meaningless by itself.

I will make a case for [excel-tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-tables) as a new tag to rise from its burninated ashes, though.

As prosaic as the name sounds, tables are actually a [useful feature of Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx), not just another way of referring to any data in an Excel sheet. Looking through the questions tagged with [tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tables) and [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), a handful pertain to use of this feature. There are still several others with these tags (the majority) that have nothing to do with this feature.

So, if [excel-tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-tables) is created, it will likely be misapplied fairly often. However, with a well-crafted tag wiki excerpt and tag wiki, some of this can be avoided.

So, I say yes to creating [excel-tables](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/excel-tables) and offer to help curate the tag (cull the questions that don't belong) and write a tag wiki for it if/when it is created.

Comment: You're forgetting one thing: When tags aren't applied correctly, it's because people don't read the manual.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I'm not claiming that the tag wiki excerpt will eliminate all misuse of the tag, but it will eliminate some, hopefully enough to make the tag useful for classification.

Comment: @Excellll Not really. The tag [tag:cd] is well-documented to mean the `cd` command, but many users misuse it for the optical media (i.e. the tag [tag:compact-disc]).

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Speaking of which, I've re tagged all incorrect questions :) At least they're still being reviewed.

Comment: @gparyani There is a `cd` command tag? Wow. The vast majority of them have 0 upvotes, several have negative votes, and one FAQ about windows drive letters has a lot. Seems the whole tag exists solely to tell people to use `cd /D` in windows console.